# AsyncTask.java cannot resolve symbol for Nullable, Mainthread, WorkerThread

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-appcompat, android-annotations

I'm pretty new to android studio, but i got this error and i can't run my project. I saw a lot of answers which suggest to add the **support-annotations** dependency, but I'm using appcompat so i don't need that. Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: Appcompat doesn't include the annotations dependency

Comment: Why is your Java class in the `android.os` package?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations.html

Comment: @Commons I think this is the AsyncTask source code

Comment: yes, it's the AsyncTask source code

Comment: Since that is not your class, and it is not part of what is being compiled in your project, why do you think that this is why you cannot run your project? What are your symptoms?

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke                 virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference` that's the main reason. But i thought that both are related somehow?

Comment: Most likely, no. You might consider asking a separate Stack Overflow question, where you post a [mcve] -- the full Java stack trace and your code that is referenced from that stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Android Support Library?

To do it add this to your build.gradle file of the "app" module:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.0"
}
```

Then sync the project.

Sometimes you can do this automatically by pressing Alt+Enter over the error message and selecting the solution.

Comment: if you use support library the imports must mention them: import android.support.annotation.Nullable

Comment: Use Alt+Space to show suggestions (after the dot) of the possible imports.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the libraries that contain the imports, in your build gradle file of your module add the line inside dependencies tag:

```
api 'com.android.support:support-annotations:X.X.X'
```

or

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:X.X.X'
```

Where *X.X.X* is the version of the rest of your support libraries.

You should read [this article](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations) that explains how to implement this with more detail.